# What is $y$ for $\sin(x+iy) = 2$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

Decide $y$ For a certain complex number $z = x+ iy$ so that $$\sin(z) = 2?$$

What I think to have realised is that I need to write it in the form $$e^{x+iy}$$ but can't seem to find a way how.

Comment: How is $\sin$ defined on $\mathbb{C}$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

You may use

$$\sin(x+iy)=\sin x\cos(iy)+\cos x\sin(iy)=\sin x\cosh y+i\cos x\sinh y.$$

Then $\cos x=0,\sin x=\pm1$  (reject $-$), $y=\pm\text{arcosh}(2)$.

Answer (score 0):

You have to solve
$$
\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}=2
$$
where $z=x+iy$. This easily becomes
$$
e^{2iz}-4ie^{iz}-1=0
$$
which is a quadratic in $e^{iz}$: $t^2-4it-1=0$ has roots $i(2\pm\sqrt{3})$,

We have $e^{iz}=e^{ix-y}$, so $|e^{iz}|=e^{-y}$ and we have
$$
e^{-y}=2+\sqrt{3}\qquad\text{or}\qquad e^{-y}=2-\sqrt{3}
$$

Comment: The roots are $2\pm\sqrt5$ and they are opposite inverses of each other.

Comment: @YvesDaoust There was something that puzzled me. `;-)` Thanks!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen You're right!